# How to use variables in Jade passed via res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

First of all, I want to apologyze for my english.

I have this code on a router file:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  res.render('./game/main', {name:req.session.name, menuOp:'Home'});
}
```

And then I have the .jade that extends from another file.

[main.jade]

```
extends mainLayout

block topMenu
    -var selected = '#{menuOp}'
```

But this throws an error.
My question is... why I can print the variable but can't assign to another? I mean, the following code works fine:

```
block topMenu
    h1 #{menuOp}
```

But when I try to assign, doesn't work.

By the way, I tried this and worked too:

```
block topMenu
    -var selected = 'Home'
```

So I think the problem is that #{variable} only works to print or something.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but I think what you want is this:

```
block topMenu
    -var selected = '#' + menuOp
```

When you use the dash, Jade interprets what follows as JavaScript, so putting a variable inside a string isn't going to expand the variable.  If you literally want a new variable that puts a hash in front of the string, you can use the syntax above.

Comment: Hm, are you sure?  I tried it to make sure my answer was accurate and it worked fine for me.  How didn't it work?

Comment: Try this: `-var selected=menuOp;`

Comment: ok, that worked... but i though I have tried ~.~ Thank you. Can you put it into an answer so I can mark as accepted answer?